# Cannot convert from android.support.v4.app.Fragment to android.app.Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I'm doing my first Android app, and wanted to get straight into the ICS API. I have so far created an app using an ActionBar, with swipeable tabs using Viewpager and Fragments.

I do however experience some errors that I keep returning to.

Depending on how I implement it, it always keep going back to an "Type mismatch" error: "cannot convert from android.support.v4.app.Fragment to android.app.Fragment". I have tried removing all import references to either, and this error appears when I only use android.support.v4.app.Fragment in TabListener, FragmentActivity and my two Fragments.

The error occurs in my TabListener:

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.Log;

public class TabListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    private android.app.Fragment fragment;
    private Activity activity;
    private ViewPager pager;
    private FragmentTransaction ft;

    public TabListener(Activity activity, Fragment fragment, ViewPager pager) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.fragment = fragment;
        this.pager = pager;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft){     
        if (fragment == null) {
            ft.add(fragment, null);
        } else {
            ft.attach(fragment);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    }
}
```

By removing "android.app.FragmentTransaction ft", replacing it with just "FragmentTransaction ft", the problem goes awawy. Then new problems arise:

> The method onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab, FragmentTransaction) of type TabListener must override or implement a supertype method TabListener.java
>
> The method onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab, FragmentTransaction) of type TabListener must override or implement a supertype method TabListener.java
>
> The method onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab, FragmentTransaction) of type TabListener must override or implement a supertype method TabListener.java
>
> The type TabListener must implement the inherited abstract method ActionBar.TabListener.onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab, FragmentTransaction)    TabListener.java
>
> The type TabListener must implement the inherited abstract method ActionBar.TabListener.onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab, FragmentTransaction)  TabListener.java
>
> The type TabListener must implement the inherited abstract method ActionBar.TabListener.onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab, FragmentTransaction)    TabListener.java

Whats going on here?

As you may understand, I'm new to Java and Android development. I feel like I'm pretty close, but I'm not able to solve this problem. I don't understand why it want to "convert from android.support.v4.app.Fragment to android.app.Fragment when I'm not even importing android.app.Fragment anywhere.

I guess it's related to using the compatibility package. (Do I have to use this package at all when creating an app for the newest version of the SDK?)

Answer (score 130):

Try to use `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead `getFragmentManager()`

Comment: I try this TutViewerFragment viewer = (TutViewerFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.tutview_fragment);  but shows error "cannot cast from fragment to TutView Fragment"

Comment: what is parent of TutViewerFragment?

Comment: its extends from FragmentActivity

Comment: @gayavat, why when I use getSupportFragmentManager(); Android Studio says undefined!

Comment: may be it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212353/getsupportfragmentmanager-is-undefined

Comment: @gayavat hi. I am stuck at same problem. But i need to implement ViewPager in Fragment,not Activity. What should i do??

Answer (score 14):

> Whats going on here?

While the Android Support package gives you a backwards-compatible `Fragment` implementation, the `ActionBar` is *not* part of the Android Support package. Hence, `ActionBar.TabListener` is expecting native API Level 11 `Fragment` objects. Consider using ActionBarSherlock to have both an action bar and Android Support fragments.

> but then I'm left with another problem in my FragmentPagerAdapter

The `FragmentPagerAdapter` in the Android Support package is a bit messy -- it wants API Level 11 `Fragment` objects, not Android Support `Fragment` objects. However, you can clone the source to `FragmentPagerAdapter` (source is in your SDK) and create your own implementation that uses the `support.v4` flavor of `Fragment` and kin.

Comment: Cloning the FragmentPagerAdapter, and asking it to use android.app.Fragment/import android.app.FragmentManager/import android.app.FragmentTransaction seems to have worked.. No errors this time! Thanks

Comment: SLekvak, does your implementation work on api 11 and lower devices, or just on api 13+?

Answer (score 4):

I know that it has been too late to answer this question but it might help someone with the same problem.

Go to your *java* folder and click on your fragment's activity.

In the imports, replace `import android.app.Fragment;` with

`import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`

Keep the code in the *MainActivity* intact and this should help resolve the issue.

Note: If it doesn't work at once, don't worry. *Build > Rebuild project*.

Answer (score 4):

> This solution works for me

replace

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment{
}
```

with

```
public class MyFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment{
}
```

and also replace import

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

with

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the support package, and that should solve your problem. It is only needed when you need functions from Android 3.0 and above in apps for earlier versions.
In your case you get both the default Fragments from ICS, and the Fragments from the support package, and if you happen to get objects from the different packages they will not work together.

Short version; You use either an api level above Honecomb **or** the support package, not both.

Comment: I understand. I have tried removing the need to use the support package, but then I'm left with another problem in my FragmentPagerAdapter - which I can't import as "android.app.FragmentPagerAdapter".

>The return type is incompatible with FragmentPagerAdapter.getItem(int) MainFragmentActivity.java

It tries here to return fragment, which is Fragment mFragment = LatestFragment.newInstance(position);

Comment: It is perfectly reasonable to have a build target of API Level 11 or higher *and* use the Android Support package.

Comment: @CommonsWare: I was under the impression that the support package (v4) was built on features from API level 11 (the v13 package slipped my mind), but in op's case, when he develops for ICS (API>13), the contents of the packages should be supported without additional packages, or am I wrong?

Comment: @Jave: Well, I can't quite follow everything the OP wrote. :-) If you are only *deploying* to API Level 11 and higher, you can use the native `Fragment` implementation supplied by API Level 11. If you are deploying to older devices, you need to use the Android Support package, *regardless of your build target*. It's entirely possible to want an ICS build target for selective things (e.g., `CalendarContract`) that can be bypassed on older devices, yet still want to use the Android Support package for fundamental stuff that needs to be fully backwards-compatible.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Then I am with you there, My assumption was that OP was targeting and deploying on API level >13.

Comment: I was being a bit unclear, mainly because of being new to this, and bad language. I am targeting > 13

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem yesterday.

There is a really nice [page by Samsung](http://developer.samsung.com/android/technical-docs/UI-unification-with-older-Android-versions-using-ActionBarSherlock) that covers ActionBarSherlock.
Check if you use one of the imports/classes/methods on the left and replace them by the imports/classes/methods on the right.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Solved it by changing the interface from `implements ActionBar.TabListener` to `implements TabListener` and then implement the methods inside this interface. Its also mentioned the error you have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

look here:`fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_container, new HomeFragment());`
you add the fragment ,but follow,you use `replace()` method ,so you should use replace instead of `add()`