# Android: support package Fragment

Tags: android

I tried this example

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/FragmentPagerSupport.html

I build for API Level 15 and use support package as well.
This funktion causes trouble:

```
@Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return ArrayListFragment.newInstance(position);
        }
```

Error Message:

The return type is incompatible with FragmentPagerAdapter.getItem(int)

I found a similar problem but with no clear solution to me
[Cannot convert from android.support.v4.app.Fragment to android.app.Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8993348/cannot-convert-from-android-support-v4-app-fragment-to-android-app-fragment)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is an support.v13 available, use this. v4 is too old for API 15

Comment: I only see rev. 7 in android sdk manager. where do i get it and why is it not distributed by sdk manager?

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you are using this class: `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` instead of `android.app.Fragment`

Comment: then i get this error:

Type mismatch: cannot convert from MyClass.ArrayListFragment to Fragment

Comment: What's the ArrayListFragment supper class?

Answer (score 5):

1. Import `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` instead of `android.app.Fragment`.
2. Get the fragment manager using `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`

Comment: thants what eclipse suggested. 
AT Override
        public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return ArrayListFragment.newInstance(position);

brings: Type mismatch: cannot convert from MenuFragen.ArrayListFragment to Fragment

like in the example i use getSupportFragmentManager
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.menufragen);
        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());