# cannot find symbol method getSupportFragmentManager()

Tags: java, android

And in main activity I have this

```
public void showTimePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new uSharedUtility.TimePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
}
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Error:(566, 26) error: cannot find symbol method getSupportFragmentManager()
```

After searching I find out that I can make this go away [by extending from FragmentActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212353/getsupportfragmentmanager-is-undefined)

But currently my MainActivity is extending from `public class Main extends ListActivity` due to some earlier requirements.

Is there any other way I can solve this issue excepting for changing extending classes.?

Comment: no, you have to extend FragmentListActivity

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***getSupportFragmentManager()*** is method of ***FragmentActivity***. Your Parent activity should have extends FragmentActivity

Check this

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html

Comment: So I cant use ListAdapters and DatePickers inside one activity?

Comment: You have to use simple listview in layout and in FragmentActivity find out that listview and set data/adapter to it. ListActivity will not help you. Yoo can use DatePickers also in FragmentActivity.

Comment: Or extend AppCompactActivity instead of Activity

Answer (score 0):

There are other reasons for the same error message.
You might need to instead call **getFragmentManager()**

As noted in the accepted answer to this related thread:
[Difference between Fragment And FragmentActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10609268/difference-between-fragment-and-fragmentactivity)