# Can not cast android.app.fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-support-library

I've seen other posts, and they all suggest that the host activity java file is not extending android.support.v4.app.Fragment. However, I don't know how to make the hosting java file extend android.support.v4.app.Fragment. 
I've tried adding the dependency to the gradle file but that doesn't work either.

Here's the hosting activity snippet:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import course.examples.fragmentstaticlayout.TitlesFragment.ListSelectionListener;

public class QuoteViewerActivity extends Activity implements ListSelectionListener{

    public static String[] mTitleArray;
    public static String[] mQuoteArray;
    private QuotesFragment mDetailsFragment;

    private static final String TAG = "QuoteViewerActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mTitleArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Titles);
        mQuoteArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Quotes);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mDetailsFragment = (QuotesFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.details);
    }
```

The line in question is the last line of the snippet. And here is my QuotesFragment.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class QuotesFragment extends Fragment {

    private TextView mQuoteView = null;
    private int mCurrIdx = -1;
    private int mQuoteArrayLen;

    private static final String TAG = "QuotesFragment";

    public int getShownIndex() {
        return mCurrIdx;
    }

    public void showQuoteAtIndex(int newIndex) {
        if (newIndex < 0 || newIndex >= mQuoteArrayLen)
            return;
        mCurrIdx = newIndex;
        mQuoteView.setText(QuoteViewerActivity.mQuoteArray[mCurrIdx]);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context){
        Log.i(TAG, getClass().getSimpleName() + ":entered onAttach()");

        super.onAttach(context);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(TAG, getClass().getSimpleName() + ":entered onCreate()");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.quote_fragment, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        mQuoteView = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.quoteView);
        mQuoteArrayLen = QuoteViewerActivity.mQuoteArray.length;

    }
```

Assuming that I'm right about the host activity not extending the support.v4, how would I do this?

Comment: obviously, you are mixing new API(13) with supportAPI .... fx: `getFragmentManager()` it doesn't exist in older API ... also  if you wana support older API than 13 you should remeber that it knows nothing about Fragments ... also basics inheritance: `android.app.Fragment` is not a base class of `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you are trying to cast `Fragment` to `SupportFragment`.

Your `QuotesFragment` is extending `SupportFragment`, and while casting you are trying to use `FragmentManager and fragment` which returns Fragment, not `supportFragment`.

Try using `geSupportFragmentManager` instead `getFragmentManager`.

Also you should extend AppCompatActivity or FragmentActivity instead of Activity for your QuoteViewerActivity

[Here is similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8993348/cannot-convert-from-android-support-v4-app-fragment-to-android-app-fragment?rq=1)

Comment: is there a preference difference between AppCompatActivity and FragmentActivity? Meaning is using one better than the other one?

Comment: Usecases are different, AppcompatActivity is latest thing. 
@jasonadams see this >> http://stackoverflow.com/a/31297546/519718

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your `getFragmentManager()` to `getSupportFragmentManager()` and extending `FragmentActivity` instead of `Activity` in your `QuoteViewerActivity`.